# Replace irregular shapes with one white pixel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some binary images (only 0 or 255 values) with many irregular shapes like this:
[image]

I would like to replace each shape with one white pixel in the center of the shape.  The rest of the pixels should be black.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: you can use scipy to get the centroid https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.centroid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- load image and ensure it is thresholded
- find contours and iterate over them finding centroid of each

If you use **OpenCV** that might look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv2.imread('irregular.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Make empty black output image, same size
result = np.zeros_like(im)

# Ensure binary
_, im = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,0)

# Find contours and iterate over them
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
   # Calculate moments for this contour to get centroid
   M = cv2.moments(c)

   # Calculate x,y coordinates of centre
   cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
   cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

   # Mark centroid in white, and tell user
   result[cY,cX] = 255
   print(f'Centroid {i+1} at location: {cX},{cY}')

# Save output file
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

**Sample Output**

```
Centroid 1 at location: 191,354
Centroid 2 at location: 572,185
```

[image]